# Need help with water valve/cartridge removal

Tags: water, pipe, valve, cartridge

Trying to replace hot water leaking cartridge and having problems removing old one out. I was able to unscrew the top part but insides stuck and won't come out easily. I've tried to force it but afraid of damaging the pipe.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to remove it safely?

Here are more pics of my attempt: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pth0f.jpg

Comment: Will the shaft turn freely now? It looks like the packing may have extruded and be prevented withdrawal, no more pliers on the threaded part of the shaft it may still be serviceable but you may need to debur the threads as it is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to answer my own question but what I ended up doing is I cut the pipe just around the valve and then installed Sharkbite ball valve over. So far it's been more than a year and no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a heat gun and heat up the outside gently (without melting the seams). That should expand the outside an free it up.